# Get JSTree data XML Format

Tags: xml, jstree

```html
 $('#jstree_div').jstree({
      core:{
          check_callback : true,
      }      
  });
  
  var tree="<div id='jstree_div'>";
      tree+="<ul>";
      tree+="<li id='j1_1' data-jstree='{'opened':true,'selected':true}><a class='jstree-clicked' href='#'> </a></li>";
      tree+="";            
      tree+="</ul>";            
      tree+="</div>";    
  appendDiv.append(tree);
```

I am trying to get the whole JSTree data, and send it to the server as an xml object to be able to save the data.
I tried

```js
var xmlString = $("#jstree_div").jstree("get_xml");   
var xmlDOM = $.parseXML(xmlString);

var DataList =[];
var items = $(xmlDOM).find("li > a");
$.each (items, function(key, val){
    DataList.push($(val));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
```

but it gives me an empty array

Comment: provide your html script

Comment: If you're using the current version of JSTree, it looks to me like it no longer contains the get_xml method. I can find documentation on it at https://old.jstree.com/documentation/xml_data, but nothing with get_xml in the current jstree api: https://www.jstree.com/api/

Comment: I guess so, Trying to find something that may have replaced it but no results so far